# Finding broken internal links in DotNetNuke

Tags: html, dotnetnuke, broken-links

Are there any automated tools that can find broken INTERNAL links on a website -- specifically for a website based on the DNN framework. (DotNetNuke).

We have looked at Xenu , but can't to see get past the login page.

Any suggestions

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I've blogged about this in great detail, including a few tools that can help you at the bottom of the [broken DotNetNuke links blog](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2797/DotNetNuke-SEO-Broken-Links-Deleted-Pages-Redirection.aspx).

Comment: thanks I will try the tools you have suggested and let you know how we go.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [IIS SEO Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/download/SEOToolkit) to find broken links. It works with any publicly accessible (or local) URL - and works quite well with DotNetNuke in my experience.

Comment: Also turns up lots of other site problems while you're at it.

Answer (score 1):

IIS SEO Toolkit doesn't work with forms authentication. So if your DNN site is behind a login page then the Toolkit won't get passed that, even if you specifiy the details in the basic or Windows options for connecting!